# Как назвать паттерн проектирования?

Tags: ооп, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть приложение с несколькими таблицами в БД. Для каждой таблицы есть соответствующий ей класс со статическими методами, отвечающими за стандартные операции CRUD c данными этой таблицы (МойКласс.save(), МойКласс.GetById(id) и т.д. ). Все классы наследуются от базового.

Не могу понять, как правильно называть такой паттерн, чтобы красиво и модно обозвать базовый класс.

UPD: Не могу ответить на свой вопрос, поэтому приведу здесь. Нужный мне паттерн называется Шлюз таблицы данных (Table Data Gateway) и описан в книге Мартина Фаулера.

UPD2: Про связь Table Data Gateway и DAO он пишет вот что:

"В [3] рассматривается аналог шлюза таблицы данных под именем объект доступа к данным (Data Access Object). В нем результаты выполнения запросов возвращаются в виде
коллекций объектов переноса данных. Мне не совсем понятно, может ли это типовое решение быть построено только на основе таблицы. Концепции и идеи, изложенные в
книге, применимы как к шлюзу таблицы данных, так и к шлюзу записи данных.
В моей книге это типовое решение получило другое имя — шлюз таблицы данных. Во-
первых, мне хотелось, чтобы имя типового решения отображало его связь с более обшей
концепцией шлюза. Кроме того, термин объект доступа к данным (Data Access Object) и
его аббревиатура DAO уже давно применяются компанией Microsoft для обозначения
собственной технологии."

Comment: А какой смысл в наследовании, если методы статические? Вообще, такой паттерн есть, и называется DAO (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object ).

Comment: В базовом классе будут общие для всех методы, типа коннекта к БД.

Я пока не разобрался, точно ли подходит под мое описание DAO, но нашел, как называется то, что мне нужно -- Table Data Gateway.

http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/table-data-gateway.html

Comment: > Для каждой таблицы есть соответствующий ей класс со статическими методами, отвечающими за стандартные операции CRUD c данными этой таблицы (МойКласс.save(), МойКласс.GetById(id) и т.д. 

Если заменить статические методы обычными, то будет вполне типичный DAO.

Comment: Table Data Gateway из статьи по ссылке и есть DAO.

Comment: >чтобы красиво и модно обозвать базовый класс

почему-то вспоминается классическое "так вам ехать или шашечки?"

Comment: Nofate, Насколько я понимаю суть, это скорее DAO -- реализация TDG, чем наоборот) Хотя пока не понимаю, действительно ли это справедливо.

DreamChild, таки напрасный сарказм. Вопрос касается исключительно "шашечек". А "уехал" я уже давно, реализация-то готова.

Comment: Обычно такие классы доступа к данным называют ...Repository, хоть это и расходится с классическим определением паттерна repository, но вам нужна подходящая метафора, а не "паттерны превыше всего"